Return the rows from database which matches the given longitude and lattitude against the geometry column : postgress with postgis enabled
first of all , I have dataset like this in json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            87.62457877000008,
                            27.362144082000043
                        ],
                        ...
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "STATE_CODE": 1,
                "DISTRICT": "TAPLEJUNG",
                "GaPa_NaPa": "Aathrai Tribeni",
                "Type_GN": "Gaunpalika",
                "Province": "1"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}

I dumped the data using this function:
const knex = require("./connection");
const fs = require("fs");

const insertData = async () => {
  console.log("Inserting municipality data");
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync("utils/municipality.json", "utf8")
  );

  const dataToInsert = jsonData.features.map((data) => {
    const { properties, geometry } = data;
    let {
      STATE_CODE,
      DISTRICT = "",
      GaPa_NaPa,
      Type_GN,
      Province,
    } = properties;

    // Ensure DISTRICT is a string
    DISTRICT = DISTRICT.toString();
    Province = Province.toString();
    GaPa_NaPa = GaPa_NaPa.toString();

    return {
      state_code: STATE_CODE,
      district: DISTRICT,
      gapa_napa: GaPa_NaPa,
      type_gn: Type_GN,
      province: Province,
      geometry: knex.raw(
        `ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${JSON.stringify(geometry)}'), 4326)`
      ),
    };
  });

  try {
    const tableExists = await knex.schema.hasTable("tbl_municipality");
    if (tableExists) {
      await knex("tbl_municipality").insert(dataToInsert);
      console.log("Municipality data inserted");
    } else {
      console.log("tbl_municipality table does not exist");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error inserting municipality data", err);
  }
};

but i want to  implement the getrequest based on lat and long


const getMunicipalityData = async function (req, res, next) {
  let { lat, long } = req.query;
  if (lat === undefined || long === undefined) {
    lat = 27;
    long = 87;
  }

  console.log(lat, long);
  const rawQuery = `
     SELECT *
    FROM tbl_municipality
    WHERE ST_Intersects(
      geometry,
      ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326), 01)
    )
  ;

  try {
    const result = await knex.raw(rawQuery, [long, lat]);
    const data = result.rows;
    console.log("Query result:", data);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error querying the database:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Database query failed" });
  }
};

problem is : even i query the databased based on longitutue and lattitude from original json data, it returns empty list
i want the data which it corresponds to the given longitude and lattitude
